# Is there a way to make more then 10 layers?

Tags: layers

So, I've been getting used to animating, But,

I Can't find a way to make more then 10 layers. I want to do this to make cool flip book animations.

Comment: How about using keyframes instead of layers for animation, seems that you're trying to abusing layers. You could also  use images in the VSE.